# How to redefine (via `environ` package) the `pmatrix` environment?

Tags: environments

I want to redefine the `pmatrix` environment provided by the `amsmath` package (and changed by the `mathtools` package) for adding good-looking delimiters. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,environ}
\RenewEnviron{pmatrix}{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}
```

The `\PARENS` command is provided by the `mtpro2` package to get curved left/right parentheses. But it does not work. Furthermore, there's a starred version `pmatrix*` (with an optional arg `l`/`c`/`r`): I don't have any idea either. The code I can give is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,environ}
\RenewEnviron{pmatrix*}[1][c]{\PARENS{\begin{matrix*}[c]\BODY\end{matrix*}}}
```

I mailed to `environ` package's author Will Robertson, but there's no reply. He may come here usually. So I logged in and posted.

(The question is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802117/how-to-redifine-via-environ-package-the-pmatrix-environment.)

Comment: I edited your post. Please don't just put a link there.

Answer (score 11):

`\NewEnviron` can define a environment that is never defined before, and `\RenewEnviron` can only redefine a environment that is defined by `\NewEnviron`. If we use `\RenewEnviron` to redefine a predefined environment, we'll get an error:

> `! LaTeX Error: \env@pmatrix@save@env undefined.`

It seems a bug of `environ`. Here is the solution:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{environ}

\let\pmatrix\relax
\let\endpmatrix\relax
\NewEnviron{pmatrix}{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}

\expandafter\let\csname pmatrix*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endpmatrix*\endcsname\relax
\NewEnviron{pmatrix*}[1][c]{\PARENS{\begin{matrix*}[#1]\BODY\end{matrix*}}}
```

Comment: the `environ` package uses the same internal command to define an environment or to redefine one. To do that, it has a placeholder for `\(re)newcommand` and `\(re)newenvironment`. In a `\NewEnviron`, everything is defined using `\new...`. In a `\RenewEnviron`, everything is defined using `\renew...`. What we would like here is renew some macros (`\pmatrix` and `\endpmatrix`), but create new (internal) macros.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks, I got it. But it seems a bug (or unpleasing feature) of `environ`.

Comment: These worked perfectly. Thanks you for your efforts on my problem!

Answer (score 7):

My solution is based on Leo Liu's, but quicker if you want to redefine many environments in such a way:

```
\newcommand{\OverwriteEnviron}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@parse\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@save@env\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\let\csname env@#1@process\endcsname\relax%
  \NewEnviron{#1}%
}

\OverwriteEnviron{pmatrix*}[1][c]{\PARENS{\begin{matrix*}[#1]\BODY\end{matrix*}}}
```