# Is there a way to replace an environment with a command?

Tags: macros, environments

Under certain conditions (triggered by selection of a package option) I would like to change specific environments into margin notes. However `marginnote` is not itself an environment, but a command that takes its contents as an argument. So what I want to do is replace

```
\begin{someenvironment}
...
\end{someenvironment}
```

with

```
\marginnote{
...
}
```

but I clearly cannot do this with something like

```
\renewenvironment{someenvironment}
    {\marginnote{ }
    { }}
```

What is the correct way to replace an environment with a command that takes the environment's contents as an argument?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) may be of help here. You define an environment using

```
\NewEnviron{<env>}{%
  % environment contents
}
```

and the contents of the environment is available in the macro `\BODY`. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron{someenvironment}{%
  \marginnote{\BODY}% Place contents of <someenvironment> in a \marginnote
}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with a margin note.
\begin{someenvironment}
This is a margin note.
\end{someenvironment}
\end{document}
​
```

`\NewEnviron` has a macro-like look to it, so the usage should be fairly intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, thigh it ended up begin [a bit more complicated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9771/how-to-redefine-via-environ-package-the-pmatrix-environment) in my case. I'm redefining an already defined environment, and end up with a lot of floats, so I had to   
`\usepackage[maxfloats=36]{morefloats}` and `\let\existingenv ... \NewEnviron{existingenv}...`.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? You are still using `\begin{someenvironment}...`, not writing `\someenvironment{...`

Comment: @ToivoSäwén: The OP *thought* there is a need to switch from an environment to a macro/command, because they wanted to capture the contents of the environment (similar to how a macro would capture its argument), with the latter being impossible. This was a *false* premise, so this and other answers point to ways of using the original setup (an environment).

Answer (score 2):

Note also that you can use `xparse` (now included directly inside LaTeX), recent enough versions provide `b` or `+b` arguments (to allow multiple paragraphs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{marginnote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewDocumentEnvironment{someenvironment}{+b}{%
  \marginnote{#1}% Place contents of <someenvironment> in a \marginnote
}{}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with a margin note.
\begin{someenvironment}
This is a margin note.
\end{someenvironment}
\end{document}
```

I also got lucky sometimes by replacing `{...}` with `\bgroup...\egroup`, but it seems that it's not working for all functions.

Comment: In detail, the `b` argument specifier has been introduced in `xparse` in March 2019, and `xparse` is part of the format since October 2020.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Btw, any idea why `\bgroup...\egroup` sometimes work, sometimes don't?

Comment: they only work when the macros are designed not to take arguments normally but use something like a trailing `\setbox0=\vbox` so as to avoid freezing catcodes and improve efficiency (plain's `\footnote` does this)

Comment: Primitives accepting arguments delimited by `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are basically the boxing primitives: `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vtop`, `\vcenter`, `\halign`. And IIRC `\noalign` and `\insert`. I might've forgotten something but anyway it's a relatively restricted list.