# Append the contents of an environment to a hook using \gappto

Tags: macros, environments, etoolbox, hooks

I have a global hook (=macro) that should be appended to whenever an environment is executed. (Here, defined by the `\bhook`-`\ehook` pair.) However, I was unable to derive a working solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\myhook{}
\gappto{\myhook}{hooked!}

% How to define these macros?
\newcommand\bhook{\gappto{\myhook}\bgroup}
\newcommand\ehook{\egroup}

% Usage, result should be equivalent to
% \gappto{\myhook}{hook this!}
\bhook{hook this!}\ehook

\begin{document}
  \myhook
\end{document}
```

Compilation of this code results in an error, as does replacing `\bgroup`/`\egroup` with `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` or

```
{\if0=`}\fi
```

and

```
\if0=`{\fi}
```

[Is there a way to replace an environment with a command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45316/8057) No, the `\NewEnviron` from the environ package doesn't work here either. (At least for my special case -- I want to allow pretty much everything inside this environment.)

Is this a deficiency in `\gappto`, or why do the "usual tricks" not work? Would this be easier to achieve using `\def` and friends?

**EDIT**: To further complicate matters, the `\bhook` and `\ehook` commands are to be embedded in a custom environment:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testhook}{}{\bhook}{\ehook}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to macros *must* be enclosed in *explicit* braces if they consist of more than one token (and are not “delimited” in the macro's definition, but `\newcommand` defined macros always require arguments in braces).

If you really want a syntax

```
\bhook Hook this!\ehook
```

you can say

```
\long\def\bhook#1\ehook{\gappto{\myhook}{#1}}
```

so that the argument to `\bhook` is effectively delimited and ends at the first `\ehook` token at the same brace level.

A different approach with `environ` might be

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hook}{%
  \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\myhook\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
```

so that

```
\begin{hook}
Hook this!
\end{hook}
```

would be equivalent to the call above.

Comment: Thank you. The `\long\def`... works for the given example, but I don't seem to be able to use `\bhook` and `\ehook` in the begin and end blocks of a custom environment, such as `\NewDocumentEnvironment{testhook}{}{\bhook}{\ehook}`. Why?

Comment: @user946850 The argument to `\bhook` ends when TeX scans `\ehook`, which doesn't happen because what's seen is only `\end{testhook}`: TeX doesn't expand tokens when gathering an argument.