# What happens if you use a command form of an environment?

Tags: environments

Despite the fact that tex.SX is warning me that this seems to be a subjective question, it isn't.  (I don't think it's a dup either, [this was the closest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/is-there-a-way-to-replace-an-environment-with-a-command) I found.) I want to know *precisely* what happens if I do the following.

1. Define an environment, or use one already provided.  Call it `thm`.
2. Recall that it's suppose to be used like

   ```
   \begin{thm}
   stuff
   \end{thm}
   ```
3. Get lazy and do this instead:

   ```
   \thm{stuff}
   ```

I see that at the very least, the numbering works right but apparently I never leave the environment.  But that is just my looking at the pdf; I don't really have any idea what is going on when I do this.  Any specifics would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: By the way, I realize this might be some gross violation of TeXitude, but I just want to know what I should expect should I be so lazy.  Not suggesting I would ever do something so gauche.

Comment: Depends on the environment. Try with `itemize`, `center` or `amsmsth`'s `align` for some examples where you need the end code.

Comment: Don't get lazy, get an editor that helps you with your stuff and do parts of the typing for you.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{wombat}{\itshape\huge}{\par}
\begin{document}
text
\wombat{text}
text
\end{document}

Comment: Regarding the editor, ordinarily I'd agree, but in this case my use case was taking something with commands and now in a different class it needs environments, and since these answers confirmed that this is a bad idea, I ended up laboriously piecing together a sed script for this - getting newlines in Mac/BSD sed was a pain but anyway it's all over now.

Comment: Related question, [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nice question, with an answer that's not going to be short, even if a short answer to the question “can I use the macro form of an environment?” would be possible, quoting Marcel Marceau in Mel Brooks' “Silent Movie”: ***NON***.

First of all, I recall that `\newenvironment{foo}[<n>]{<start>}{<end>}` defines the macros `\foo` and `\endfoo`, but just because it *has* to, as TeX only knows macros.

Such macros can be used in defining other environments, but should never appear in the body of a document. And when I say *never*, I mean it.

Therefore code such as

```
\newenvironment{foo}
  {a}
  {b}
\newenvironment{baz}
  {c\foo}
  {d\endfoo}
```

is legal and even slightly better than `\newenvironment{baz}{c\begin{foo}}{d\end{foo}}`, because it saves a level of grouping and will give a better error message in case `\end{baz}` is misplaced.

As a number of questions on the same subject shows, using `\foo` or `\baz` in a document can lead to very unexpected results. For instance,

```
\abstract{Text...}
```

will, with most document classes, leads to wrong typesetting of the whole document. See [The abstract environment changes the \linewidth for the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25833/the-abstract-environment-changes-the-linewidth-for-the-whole-document) that has several questions linked to it as duplicate.

Other cases are even more blatantly wrong: if you try

```
\align{
<eq 1> \\
<eq 2> \\
<eq 3>}
```

according to your attempt, you'll have a very nasty surprise.

The body of the environment is almost never an argument to a command and, even when it is, it is not an argument to the macro having the environment's name.

Your “lazy” example `\thm{stuff}` will setup things for a theorem: step the counter, typeset the label and change the font to italics. Such is the job of `\thm`. In this case `{` and `}` don't delimit an argument, but just form a group; not a big deal, because “stuff” will be typeset anyway. However, italics will continue.

The macros `\begin` and `\end` are not just placeholders: they do several actions. They open and close a group, so font or line width changes will be local (see the `abstract` example and the note about the font with `\thm`). They also set the current environment name, in order to help you in case nesting is improper. The `\end` part also adds some bookkeeping at the end, which most basic environments such as `list` hook at.

I'm the last one to say that being lazy is bad, but the above remarks should be enough to stop you trying being *that* lazy.

The converse, that is, using a macro as an environment, can work. Mostly it does, in some occasions it just *seems* to work; therefore I don't recommend doing it.

Comment: Will there be different (better?) results if i group the begin-macro like this: `{\abstract Text...}`?

Comment: @MaPePeR No: the `\endabstract` macro would not be executed, which does important things. Some envs might work with this trick, some won't (again, try `align`); you have to look into each one to see whether it works: why bother?

Comment: @MaPePeR Just use the tools like you are supposed to. Don't use an environment as a simple command, don't use a screwdriver as a hammer, don't use an extension cord to build a tent.

Comment: My thought process was, that at least some of the changes done by the begin macro would only apply to the group and would automatically disabled again when the group ends. I would never do such thing. I was just curious.

Comment: "I'm the last one to say that being lazy is bad, but the above remarks should be enough to stop you trying being that lazy." - nice!

Answer (score 7):

Fundamentally `\newenviroment{<env>}[<args>]{<begin>}{<end>}` defines *two* macros: one associated with the start of the environment and one with the end of the environment, simplistically turning

```
\begin{<env>}[<args>]
...
\end{<env>}
```

into

```
\<env>[<args>]
...
\end<env>
```

However, using the environment form additionally provides a limited scope to any changes made within the environment in the form of a *group*. For example, consider

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.

\begin{itemize}
  \item An item
  \item Another item
\end{itemize}

Lorem ipsum.

\itemize
  \item An item
  \item Another item

Lorem ipsum.

\end{document}
```

Note how the environment usage of `itemize` reverses the list style indentation after `\end{itemize}` while the "lazy" method (without an `\end...`) doesn't restore the regular layout. Even if you were to use the command-form `\<env>[<args>]` ... `\end<env>`, it's best to stick to the environment use.

Essentially it may boil down to the environment you use. For example, theorems tend to set their "QED" during `\end<theorem>`. Other environments *require* and `\end<env>` (like [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or even just the `verbatim` environment).