# newenvironment vs newcommand?

Tags: macros, environments

Can someone explain me this following strange bahavior?

The code is

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\pippo}{Pippo}
\begin{document}
\begin{pippo}  
\end{pippo}
\end{document}
```

The output is

```
Pippo
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311118/what-happens-if-you-use-a-command-form-of-an-environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\begin{foo}` is essentially `\begingroup\foo` and `\end{foo}` is `\endfoo\endgroup` if `\endfoo` is defined, and just `\endgroup` otherwise.  So it is usually  possible to call a command as an environment.