# Custom environment with minipages causes "Illegal parameter number in definition of \end"

Tags: environments

*Using MiKTeX with PDFLaTeX on Windows*

I want to create an environment that contains two minipages; the first one has a description item, and the second has a small text (or picture). This piece of code works as I want:

```
{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{description}
    \item[Label] Description
\end{description}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    Second minipage
\end{minipage}
}
```

I wanted to create a macro or environment to make it easy for me to introduce this kind of content. So I create the following environment with two arguments:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}[2]% 1:label, 2:second minipage text
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{description}
        \item[#1] % Description
}%
{%
    \end{description}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        #2
    \end{minipage}
}
```

But when I try to use it with

```
\begin{myenvironment}{Label}{Second minipage text}
Description text
\end{myenvironment}
```

I get `Illegal parameter number in definition of \endmyenvironment.` pointing to the line that finishes the `newenvironment` declaration. After some hours struggling with this I tried using double hashes (`##`) and got two new different errors: `` You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode `` and `` You can't use `macro parameter character #' in internal vertical mode ``. This time the errors were pointing to the lines when I wanted to use the environment, but had no complaints on the definition.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: This issue is known - the arguments/parameters are not visible within the `\end` part of the environment definition. [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) makes it available, or you should use [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ). Alternatively, define the arguments in macros that you use within the `\end` segment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner. Had just found out and posted my own answer beforse seeing your comments. I will check those packages!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `##` had nothing to do with my problem. It seems that [you cannot use arguments inside of the closing or ending code of a custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument). There are workarounds for this, but in my opinion this should be a **must have** feature. Using a possible workaround ---an auxiliary variable---, I arrived to this working environment:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}[2]%
{%
    \def\myenvargumentII{#2}    
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{description}
        \item[#1] % Description
}%
{%
    \end{description}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \myenvargumentII
    \end{minipage}
}
```

This solution arrived late. In the meantime I had managed to solve my problem with a `\newcommand`<sup>a</sup> with 3 arguments:

```
\newcommand{\myminipages}[3]% 1:label, 2:secondminipage, 3:Description
{%
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{description}
            \item[#1] #3
        \end{description}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        #2
    \end{minipage}
    \medskip % vertical space
}
```

Which can be used with:

```
\myminipages{Label}{Second minipage text}{Description text}
```

Hope it helps.

---

[a] It seems that there is no particular advantage of the `newcommand` approach over the `newenvironment` approach, at least for this use. More [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102141/what-are-the-consideration-when-choosing-either-newcommand-or-newenvironment) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337809/newenvironment-vs-newcommand).