# Replace everything inside eqnarray* by a given text

Tags: macros, equations, displaystyle

Is there any simple (method/macro,..) to replace everything inside all `eqnarray*` by a simple given text. More precisely 
for example I want to replace

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
x     & = & \frac{1}{2}at_1^2 + v_0t_1 + x_0\\
t_1^2 & = & \frac{2x}{g}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

or any `eqnarray*` by

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Math inside}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

best regards.

**Edit**: it would be nice if this also works for `align`, `displaymath`,....
It should save the environment structure, and replace the content inside it.

Comment: First of all, don't use `eqnarray`... See why here: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf. Then, what you want is: whenever you use one of those environments, you want a simple text to be printed instead of its contents?

Comment: Do you have any approaches yourself yet? It would be interesting to have them as a starting point, or you could explain a little more, what you want to achieve in total (hand out a script where the formulae are missing, so that the students can fill that out while attending the lecture?)

Comment: The answers here may solve your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9771/how-to-redefine-via-environ-package-the-pmatrix-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?  I should point out that it can only handle as many fields as I put `c`'s in the `array` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\mybox
\renewenvironment{eqnarray*}
{\par Math Inside\par\lrbox{\mybox}$\array{cccccccccccccc}}
{\endarray$\endlrbox}
\begin{document}
Here is pre text
\begin{eqnarray*}
x     & = & \frac{1}{2}at_1^2 + v_0t_1 + x_0\\
t_1^2 & = & \frac{2x}{g}
\end{eqnarray*}
Here is post text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using the [environ package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifprintmaths
\printmathsfalse % <--- Change to true to switch maths printing on.
\NewEnviron{myalign}
{\ifprintmaths
  \begin{align}\BODY\end{align}
\else
  \centering Maths printing off. \par
\fi}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{myalign}
A &= B \\
C &= D
\end{myalign}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but it sounds more like a job for text editors rather than macros. For instance, if you use `Notepad++`, you can do the following: Go to `Search` -> `Replace`, then type

```
\\begin\{eqnarray\*\}.*?\\end\{eqnarray\*\}
```

in the `Find what` box, and

```
\\begin\{eqnarray\*\}\r\\text\{Math inside\}\r\\end\{eqnarray\*\}
```

in the `Replace with` box. Now check `Wrap Around`, `Regular expression` and `. matches newline` boxes, then click `Replace All`.

[image]